# storyboard, self presentViewController, iOS 6, blank screen

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am using storyboards, I have one viewcontroller and on click I need to show another view controller modally. I am trying using this code

```
[self presentViewController:zoomV animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I am coming up with a blank screen.
This is how I create

```
zViewController *zoomV = [[zViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:zoomV animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I tried researching this and some answers revolve around using storyboards and not having a rootviewcontroller associated. So what I have is in the initial scene I have a navigationController, and from there I drag to another Viewcontroller a relationship which defines it as a rootViewcontroller. Is that sufficient ? or is this irrelevant?

Comment: root view controller has nothing to do with presenting a modal controller. Is the code you have above in the root view controller? How are you creating zoomV -- I suspect your problem is there.

Comment: I do instantiate zoomV, and do hit its viewdidload, and I do hit that method at runtime.

Comment: Where are you creating zViewController's view's hierarchy? In the storyboard, of in its separate xib or by code?

Comment: no I added a ViewController in the storyboard, setup its UI Via Interface Builder ( it has a scollview and an imageview), I then created a class with the same name with .h and .m file. and associated it with the Viewcontroller in the storyboard. I should mention that in my storyboard there are no arrows hitting that zViewController, it just exists on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have your zViewController in your storyboard, you should instantiate your zViewController using `UIStoryboard` `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.
In your first view controller, instead of creating the zViewController using alloc/init do this, of course setting an identifier for your zViewController in your storyboard.

```
zViewController *zoomV = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:zoomV 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:NULL];
```

Also you could accomplish the same using a segue and executing it directly, without the need of instantiating the zViewController, but is up to you.

As a second(small) comment, do not name classes starting with lowercase in ObjC :).

Answer (score 0):

You may refer below snippet for story board:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
AddNameViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNameViewController.m"];
[sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```